# Unable to get the canvas on screen while using Three.js

Tags: three.js

I am Trying to just write a simple simple hello cube program in three.js but the canvas just doesn't appear on screen
Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="./three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
<body>
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my script file:

```
const scene=new THREE.Scene()
const geometry=new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1)
const material=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xff0000})
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ); 
scene.add( cube );
const sizes={
    width:800,
    height:600
}
const camera= new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70,sizes.width/sizes.height,)
scene.add(camera)
const canvas=document.getElementById("c")
console.log( canvas )
const renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas:canvas
})
renderer.setSize(sizes.width,sizes.height)
renderer.render( scene,camera );
```

I noticed that the console.log(canvas) returns null but wasn't able to find the reason for it.

Also the console returns

```
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'width')
    at new Fo (three.min.js:7:411120)
```

Comment: Got it! just had to change the id